# Not sure why my code is throwing the error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am rendering my React App on my server and am really close, but coming across a bug. I've searched online and all the other answers didn't fix the bug. I get the error `Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)".` I have provided the server code, the index, and the app. All the current answers say to wrap the rendered component in  which I did, but still get the error. The `/` route renders the App Component.

server code:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const error = () => res.status(404).send('404');
  const htmlFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '../build', 'index.html');
  fs.readFile(htmlFilePath, 'utf8', (err, htmlData) => {
    if(err) {
      error()
    } else {
      match({ routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirect, ssrData) => {
        if(err) {
          error()
        } else if(redirect) {
          res.redirect(302, redirect.pathname + redirect.search);
        } else if(ssrData) {
          const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)
          const provider = react.createElement(Provider, { store: store }, [RouterContext]);
          const ReactApp = renderToString(provider);
          const RenderedApp = htmlData.replace('{{SSR}}', ReactApp);
        } else {
          error()
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

index:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

App:

```
class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.info();
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ info }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Error: `Unexpected token (8:15)`

```
   6 |   switch(action.type) {
   7 |     case TEST_CASE:
>  8 |       return { ...state, check: true };
     |                ^
   9 |     case REAL_CASE:
  10 |       return { ...state, check: false};
```

Comment: You can't use es6 features like object rest spread in vanilla node. You either need to compile a server bundle with webpack, or not use that feature.

Comment: I installed `babel-polyfill` and did `require('babel-polyfill')` at the very top of my server code and I still get the error, do I need to do anything else?

Comment: As Andy said, you need to use webpack to bundle codes, or put `require('babel-register')` at the top of your server code, create a `.babelrc` to set the preset like `es2015`.

Comment: @joethemow you need babel-register to get syntax changes, polyfill only gives you native objects like WeakMap http://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-use-es6-in-nodejs/

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the `<RouterContext />` with `<Provider />` component. Your server code will look like this:

```js
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)
const ReactApp = renderToString(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <RouterContext {...ssrData} />
  </Provider>
)
```

Comment: Ah ok this makes sense, but how would I do it without the anchor tags? Node does not recognize that syntax, that's why I used `react.createElement`

Comment: `const provider = React.createElement(Provider, { store: store }, [ RouterContext ])` And pass the `provider` to the `renderToString()`.

Comment: So when I add the route to my reducers `(createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers))` I get an error. `switch(action.type) {
   7 |     case STATUS:
>  8 |       return { ...state, status: true };` Unexpected token

Comment: I updated my question with the error and updated code.

Comment: That error is not related to the original question. Anyway, you need to use babel-polyfill to support the object spread operator.

Comment: I installed `babel-polyfill` and did `require('babel-polyfill')` at the very top of my server code and I still get the error, do I need to do anything else?